# Weird SignalR error

Tags: c#, multithreading, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using SignalR to send messages back to a browser about a long running process.  I am using the System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim to run in a separate thread.  This is the error:

```
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : SignalR exception thrown by Task: System.AggregateException: One or
more errors occurred. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the 
connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean 
throwOnDisconnect)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Flush()
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.OutputStream.Flush()
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerResponse.<Flush>b__0()
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Action func)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed     
the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean   
throwOnDisconnect)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Flush()
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.OutputStream.Flush()
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerResponse.<Flush>b__0()
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Action func)<---
```

I saw some similar errors on the SignalR issues tracker.  There was something about using:

```
 TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += new EventHandler((s, arg) => 
 {
     arg.SetObserved();
     ((AggregateException)arg.Exception).Handle(ex =>
     {
         // Do something with ex (log or ignore...)
         return true;
     });
 }
```